# If select return null then select different select

Tags: sql

We need to do this:

```
select * 
from table1 as t
where t.num = 111
orderby t.createon
```

If no records where returns - do different select:

```
select * 
from table1 as t
orderby t.createon
```

There is any way to join these selects?
Thanks!

Comment: Your heading suggests data from a different table is required, but your example suggests a different condition from the SAME table is required. Which is itt?

Comment: You are right - I changed the title

Comment: @Nom use of `EXISTS` ... `SQL Server`

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    table1 as t
WHERE
    EXISTS((SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE num = 111) AND t.num = 111)
        OR NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM table1 where num = 111)
ORDER BY
    t.createon
```